# how to add validation in javascript on form so that it should not append form when last row is empty (should not create another row untill all fields)

Tags: javascript, validation, append

```js
    function add_variant(){
    
        var thickness=document.forms["create_product"]["thickness"].value;
        var thickness_unit=document.forms["create_product"]["thickness_unit"].value;
        var product_qty=document.forms["create_product"]["product_qty"].value;
        var product_cost_price=document.forms["create_product"]["product_cost_price"].value;
        var product_unit=document.forms["create_product"]["product_unit"].value;
        var product_color=document.forms["create_product"]["product_color"].value;
        var thickness_dim =document.forms["create_product"]["thickness"].value;

        console.log("thick"+thickness);
        console.log("thick dim"+thickness_dim);
        
            if(thickness == null || thickness == "", thickness_dim ==""|| thickness_dim==null)
            {
             alert('you must filled previous data');
             return false;
            }
           
             var temp = document.getElementById("product_dimension").content;
             var copy = document.importNode(temp,true);
             document.getElementById("product_description").appendChild(copy);
             
            }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
                  <label>Product Variants</label>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" id="add_variant" onclick="add_variant()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add Variant</a>
                </div>

<div id="product_description">
               <div class="row" >
               
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Actions</label><br>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Thickness</label>
                       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="thickness" id="thickness">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Thickness Unit</label>
                       <select class="form-control"name="thickness_unit" id="thickness_unit">
                        <option>mm</option>
                        <option>feet</option>
                        <option>Square feet</option>
                        <option>meter</option>
                        <option>mm square</option>
                        <option>Steel Gauge</option>
                       </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Qty.</label>
                       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_qty" id="product_qty">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Cost Price</label>
                       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_cost_price" id="product_cost_price">
                      </div>
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Unit</label>
                       <select class="form-control" name="product_unit" id="product_unit">
                        <option>Sheet</option>
                        <option>No</option>
                       </select>
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Color</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_color" id="product_color">
                      </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               
               
               
               
               
               <div>
              <template   id="product_dimension">
               <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Actions</label><br>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Thickness</label>
                   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="thickness" id="thickness">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Thickness Unit</label>
                   <select class="form-control"name="thickness_unit" id="thickness_unit">
                    <option>mm</option>
                    <option>feet</option>
                    <option>Square feet</option>
                    <option>meter</option>
                    <option>mm square</option>
                    <option>Gauge</option>
                   </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Product Qty.</label>
                   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_qty" id="product_qty">
                  </div>
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Cost Price</label>
                       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_cost_price" id="product_cost_price">
                      </div>
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Unit</label>
                       <select class="form-control" name="product_unit" id="product_unit">
                        <option>Sheet</option>
                        <option>Nos</option>
                       </select>
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Product Color</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_color" id="product_color">
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 
               </div>
              </template>
              </div>
```

i am new to java script i am trying to add some validations on my add product form in which i am trying to perform some append function in whixh i want to append a div but if the previous row is empty then it should not add/append new row but while doing so it just check validation for the 1st row when i add 2 nd add try to add 3rd it shows error

will please anybody help me to solve this,here is my code

JS:
function add_variant(){

```
    var thickness=document.forms["create_product"]["thickness"].value;
    var thickness_unit=document.forms["create_product"]["thickness_unit"].value;
    var product_qty=document.forms["create_product"]["product_qty"].value;
    var product_cost_price=document.forms["create_product"]["product_cost_price"].value;
    var product_unit=document.forms["create_product"]["product_unit"].value;
    var product_color=document.forms["create_product"]["product_color"].value;
    var thickness_dim =document.forms["create_product"]["thickness"].value;

    console.log("thick"+thickness);
    console.log("thick dim"+thickness_dim);
    
        if(thickness == null || thickness == "", thickness_dim ==""|| thickness_dim==null)
        {
         alert('you must filled previous data');
         return false;
        }
       
         var temp = document.getElementById("product_dimension").content;
         var copy = document.importNode(temp,true);
         document.getElementById("product_description").appendChild(copy);
         
        }
```

[image]

```html
               <div id="product_description">
                     <div class="row" >
                         <div class="col-sm-1">
                          <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa- 
     trash"></i></button>
                    </div>
                   <!--further fields-->
                 </div>

 
    <template   id="product_dimension">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
    </button>
<!--further fields->
</div>
</div>
</template>
      `
```

Comment: Can you plz share the complete code JS/HTML/CSS

Comment: sure here its is
<div id="product_description">
<div class="row" >               
<div class="col-sm-1">
                     <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                 </div>
  <!--further fields-->
         </div>
               </div>

Comment: I don't see it. Plz check again!

Comment: updated after 1st check its not giving alert message

Comment: Sorry I was a little busy, This is what you wanted right: https://shrutimenkudle.netlify.app/

Comment: I think fields like quantity and thickness should not go below 0, because that will not make any sense.

Comment: exactly ..thats what i want

Comment: I have added the code here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```js
const addVariant = document.getElementById("add_variant");
const productDescription = document.getElementById("product_description");
const errorAlert = document.querySelector(".alert");

const template = `<div class="row my-4 p-3 rounded productTemp">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Actions</label>
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Thickness</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="thickness" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Thickness Unit</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="thickness_unit">
        <option>mm</option>
        <option>feet</option>
        <option>Square feet</option>
        <option>meter</option>
        <option>mm square</option>
        <option>Gauge</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Product Qty.</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_qty" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Product Cost Price</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_cost_price" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Product Unit</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="product_unit">
        <option>Sheet</option>
        <option>Nos</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2">Product Color</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_color" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;

function addAlert(message) {
  errorAlert.classList.add("show");
  errorAlert.innerHTML = message;
  setTimeout(() => {
    errorAlert.classList.remove("show");
  }, 3000);
}

addVariant.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const productTemp = document.querySelectorAll(".productTemp");
  const lastElement = productTemp[productTemp.length - 1];

  const thickness = lastElement.querySelector('[name="thickness"]');
  const thicknessUnit = lastElement.querySelector('[name="thickness_unit"]');
  const productQty = lastElement.querySelector('[name="product_qty"]');
  const productPrice = lastElement.querySelector('[name="product_cost_price"]');
  const productUnit = lastElement.querySelector('[name="product_unit"]');
  const productColor = lastElement.querySelector('[name="product_color"]');

  if (
    thickness.value !== "" &&
    thicknessUnit.value !== "" &&
    productQty.value !== "" &&
    productPrice.value !== "" &&
    productUnit.value !== "" &&
    productColor.value !== ""
  ) {
    productDescription.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template);
  } else {
    addAlert("Fields can not be empty! ");
  }
});
```

```css
.productTemp {
  background-color: #2c3035;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<body class="bg-dark text-white">


  <div class="container mt-5 bg-dark text-white">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade mb-5" role="alert"></div>

    <div class="col-md-2 mb-4">
      <label class="mb-2">Product Variants</label>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="add_variant">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add Variant
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="product_description">
      <div class="row my-4 p-3 rounded productTemp">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Actions</label>
            <br />
            <button class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Thickness</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="thickness" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Thickness Unit</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="thickness_unit">
              <option>mm</option>
              <option>feet</option>
              <option>Square feet</option>
              <option>meter</option>
              <option>mm square</option>
              <option>Steel Gauge</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Product Qty.</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_qty" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Product Cost Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_cost_price" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Product Unit</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="product_unit">
              <option>Sheet</option>
              <option>No</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="mb-2">Product Color</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_color" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```